# Parallel Program with POSIX Threads Slower than Serial

Tags: c++, linux, parallel-processing, pthreads

I know this question is a duplicate one, but I couldn't find any other topic similar to my code.

The problem statement is as followed:

There is a CSV file with 16,000 lines. A serial version of the program is extracting those rows with a price (**SalePrice** is a column head in the CSV) higher than a specific value (**threshold**) given to the program with command-line arguments and calculating their **Mean** and **Standard **Derivation**** which will be used for further computations.

This larger CSV file is broken into 4 CSV files for the parallel version. Each thread is assigned to one CSV file and should do the same calculations (Calculating Mean and STD of rows with price higher than a specific value named threshold in my code).

Since the data is large enough, I don't think this is because of the multithreading overhead.

I would be thankful if someone could please help me find out what part is slowing down my parallel version?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip> 
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

#define COMMA ','
#define EMPTY_STR ""
#define FILENAME "dataset.csv"
#define CLASSIFIER "GrLivArea"
#define SALE_PRICE "SalePrice"

const int MAX_THREAD_NUMBERS = 20; 

int NUMBER_OF_THREADS;
int threshold;
int expensive_cnt[MAX_THREAD_NUMBERS];
vector<string> lines;
string head;
double _std;
long sum[MAX_THREAD_NUMBERS];
long ps[MAX_THREAD_NUMBERS];
long sumsq[MAX_THREAD_NUMBERS];
double mean;
int total_items;
int total_expensive_cnt;

struct Item
{
    int x;
    bool category;
};

vector<Item> items[MAX_THREAD_NUMBERS];

int getColNum(const string& head, const string& key)
{
    int cnt = 0;
    string cur = EMPTY_STR;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < head.size() ; i++)
    {
        if (head[i] == COMMA)
        {
            if (cur == key)
                return cnt;
            cnt++;
            cur = EMPTY_STR;
        }   
        else
        cur += head[i];
    }
    if (cur == key)
        return cnt;
    return -1;
}

vector<int> separateByComma(string s)
{
    vector<int> res;
    string cur = EMPTY_STR;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < s.size() ; i++)
        if (s[i] == COMMA)
        {
            res.push_back(stoi(cur));
            cur = EMPTY_STR;
        }
        else
        cur += s[i];

    res.push_back(stoi(cur));
    return res;
}

void* calcSums(void* tid)
{
    long thread_id = (long)tid;

    string filename = "dataset_" + to_string(thread_id) + ".csv"; 
    ifstream fin(filename);

    string head;
    fin >> head;
    int classifierColNum = getColNum(head, CLASSIFIER);
    if (classifierColNum == -1)
    {
        printf("NO GrLivArea FOUND IN HEAD OF CSV\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    int priceColNum = getColNum(head, SALE_PRICE);
    if (priceColNum == -1)
    {
        printf("NO SalePrice FOUND IN HEAD OF CSV\n");
        exit(-1);
    }


    string line;
    while (fin >> line)
    {
        vector<int> cur = separateByComma(line);

        bool category = (cur[priceColNum] >= threshold);

        Item item{cur[classifierColNum], category};

        if (category)
        {
            sum[thread_id] += item.x;
            sumsq[thread_id] += (item.x * item.x);
            expensive_cnt[thread_id]++;
        }

        items[thread_id].push_back(item);
    }


    fin.close();
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


void calcMeanSTD()
{
    string line;
    for (int i = 0 ; ; i++)
    {
        struct stat buffer;   
        string name = "dataset_" + to_string(i) + ".csv"; 
        if (!(stat (name.c_str(), &buffer) == 0))
            break;
        
        NUMBER_OF_THREADS++;
    }
  

    pthread_t threads[NUMBER_OF_THREADS];
    int return_code;
    for (long tid = 0 ; tid < NUMBER_OF_THREADS ; tid++)
    {
        return_code = pthread_create(&threads[tid], NULL, calcSums, (void*)tid);

        if (return_code)
        {
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", return_code);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    for (long tid = 0 ; tid < NUMBER_OF_THREADS ; tid++)
    {
        return_code = pthread_join(threads[tid], NULL);
        if (return_code)
        {
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_join() is %d\n", return_code);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    double total_sum = 0;
    double total_sum_sq = 0;
    total_expensive_cnt = 0;
    total_items = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS ; i++)
    {
        total_sum += sum[i];
        total_sum_sq += sumsq[i];

        total_expensive_cnt += expensive_cnt[i];
        total_items += items[i].size();
    }

    mean = total_sum / total_expensive_cnt;
    _std = sqrt((total_sum_sq - ((total_sum * total_sum) / (total_expensive_cnt))) / (total_expensive_cnt));

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    threshold = atoi(argv[1]);          

    calcMeanSTD();                

    cout << mean << " " << _std << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Please let me know if any part is not understandable.

Here are some run-time values:
`Read CSV (Serial): 0.043268s` `Calculations (Serial): 0.000151s`
The exact time calculation isn't much easy in the multithreaded version here since the calculations and file reading are done in the same while loop which is not separable here. There also many thread switches. Anyway, their sum is about: `0.14587s`

As it can be seen, the amount of time needed to read from files is almost 300 times as doing the math calculations.

Comment: Premature optimization here. The disk isn't multithreaded. There is no reason to expect the multithreaded code to be faster. And a 16,000 line file is trivial. You can read millions of lines per second with Java. You need to profile this code to find where the bottleneck is. Rather than jumping to conclusions.

Comment: @user207421 As you said, the bottleneck is the while loop reading from files: `while (fin >> line)`. So, isn't there any solution to this? Should I separate the reading input from CSVs section from the Mean, STD calculation?

Comment: I suggest that you do some benchmarking. First, without any multithreading, count the time required to read the entire file without performing any calculations on it. Afterwards, count the time with the calculations. Then repeat both tests with multithreading. Note that the first time you read a file, it may be slower, due to the operating system's file cache, so you may want to repeat the test immediately afterwards. If doing the calculations does not increase the running time of the program significantly, then there probably is no performance to be gained by multithreading.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel

Read CSV (Serial): 0.043268s

Calculations (Serial): 0.000151s

The exact time calculation isn't much easy in the multithreaded version here since the calculations and file reading are done in the same while loop which is not separable here. There also many thread switches. Anyway, their sum is about: 0.14587s

In order to measure the calculation time, I should separate it from the file input. Right?

Comment: @DaneshvarAmrollahi There is some CPU work that needs to be done (e.g. parsing numbers, etc.).  You can read a block at a time, serially, and as each block is ready, send it to a thread pool (or new thread) for parsing and math.  This should allow you to match the disk read bandwidth (with some latency) provided you have sufficient cores.  No amount of multithreading will get faster than the disk read bandwidth.  This changes if you have a parallel disk (like S3 or some RAID drives or some SSDs).

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. On my system, the parallel version on 4*4000 lines runs in ~5.6ms, while the serial version on 1*16000 lines runs in ~6.7ms. Try it again with at least 100x or preferably 1000x more data to make parallelization worthwhile.

Comment: @DaneshvarAmrol: According to the numbers you posted, reading in the file takes nearly 300 times longer than performing the calculations. In that case, there is no point in attempting to optimize your calculations, because the bottleneck is your disk speed. However, as previously stated, once you have read the file, it is probably in RAM (cached by the operating system), so reading the file will be several orders of magnitude faster. Therfore, you may want to [clear the read cache](https://www.tecmint.com/clear-ram-memory-cache-buffer-and-swap-space-on-linux/) before performing your benchmark.

Comment: @DaneshvarAmrollahi: I don't think it is necessary to separate the file input and the calculations. It should be sufficient to simply deactivate the calculations and then compare the results.

Comment: @thatotherguy  I am measuring time with the `time` command in Linux. I set the CSV file to 1e6 rows. Here is the output for parallel: `real 0m0.558s`
`user 0m2.173s`
`sys 0m0.020s`
Here is the output for serial:
`real 0m1.834s`
`user 0m1.818s`
`sys 0m0.016s`

I should be checking the`real` time here, right? The parallel version seems to be showing it's advantage now. Am I right? If yes, the reason of this because of my simple calculations (not complex enough)?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I tried cleaning cache before each run now. The results for N = 1e6 rows are:

`Serial: real 0m2.472s`

`Parallel: real 0m1.241s `

As we see, parallelization isn't helping much here. The reason for this is simple math calculations. Am I right?

Comment: @DaneshvarAmrollahi If that's 1 vs 4 threads, then that's a very nice 3.2x speedup, yes.

Comment: @DaneshvarAmrollahi: Yes, I believe that you should be looking at `real`. Simpler calculations should make multithreading less efficient, as most of the time, your program should be waiting for disk input. Therefore, you should notice that more complex calculations make multithreading more efficient. If that is not the case, then I suspect that the operating system's file cache is interfering with your benchmark. If you are unsure whether the cache has been properly cleared, you may want to reboot to be sure.

Comment: Thank you all! You can post your comments as an answer so I can approve them.

Comment: One improve direction, for your global arrays: `sum` , `sumsq`, `expensive_cnt`, ... ,need to avoid [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing)

Comment: @DaneshvarAmrollahi: Thanks for the offer, but I must go to sleep now. Note that you can post an answer to your own question: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Shared arrays indexed by thread ids cause _false sharing_. This can considerably hinder scalability if these arrays are used frequently. It has already been pointed out, but it is so serious that I emphasize it again.

Comment: @DanielLangr Thanks for emphasizing. Yes, they are frequently used. I used them in order to avoid mutex locks which increase the run-time. It is guaranteed that each thread will be accessing only it's own index of the array. 
Do you suggest argument passing between parent/child threads instead of this method? 
What exactly do you mean by scalability?

Comment: @DaneshvarAmrollahi False sharing is not related to locking. Please, read about it a bit. It causes cache contention due to updates of **different** memory locations by different threads when these locations share the same cache line mapping. There are many solutions to this problem, for example, you can introduce padding into these arrays to make sure that elements accessed by mulitple threads do not share cache lines. Or, more simply, work with thread-local variables instead of arrays, and, at the end, update the array elements only once.

Comment: Scalability in parallel computing refers to the ability to reduce runtime with respect to the growing number of threads. Ideal scalability is speed-up N (N times lower runtime) with N threads.

Comment: Note that you may want to update your question with some of your benchmark results. This would probably increase the quality of the question, increasing the chance of it being upvoted. All important information should be included as part of the question itself. A reader should not have to read the entire comments section in order to obtain all important information.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Thanks for your suggestion. I did it. I hope it's appropriate now.

Comment: @DaneshvarAmrollahi: Yes, I noticed. I upvoted both already half an hour ago. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the answers in the comment, I found out what is happening:

I tried increasing the number of rows in my CSV files to see if the parallelization is working.

The run-time values for a CSV file with 1000000 rows are:

Parallel: `real 0m0.558s user   0m2.173s sys    0m0.020s`
Serial: `real   0m1.834s user   0m1.818s sys    0m0.016s`

Since I am using 4 threads, I expect 1.834 divided by 0.558 to be near to 4 which actually is 3.28 and is fair enough.

This run-time values for smaller CSV files aren't showing these results which seems to be because of the simple math computations in my code.

The bottleneck of this code is the section where I am reading from CSV files. This section seems to be serial since it is reading from a disk.

There is also a problem of **False Sharing** in this code
which causes cache contention due to updates of different memory locations by different threads when these locations share the same cache line mapping. There are many solutions to this problem, for example, I can introduce padding into these arrays to make sure that elements accessed by multiple threads do not share cache lines. Or, more simply, work with thread-local variables instead of arrays, and, in the end, update the array elements only once.

Comment: Problems along the lines of cache effects, like `false sharing` tend to show up in the margins.  In general, when you find yourself making data structures like `a[nthread], b[nthread], ... g[nthread]`; you should really consider `struct { int a; float b; double c; ... char g; } data[nthread];` which can neatly take care of that and improve your program.